# When defining a Windows API interface in C#, do I have to define all members? Can I only define the methods I'm going to use?

Tags: c#, winapi, interface

For example, this is the full definition of the [IFileOpenDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775834%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface, a Windows Shell Interface, taken from the [Pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces/IFileOpenDialog.html) site:

```
[ComImport, Guid ( "d57c7288-d4ad-4768-be02-9d969532d960" ), InterfaceType ( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
interface IFileOpenDialog : IFileDialog
{
// Defined on IModalWindow - repeated here due to requirements of COM interop layer
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime ), PreserveSig]
int Show ( [In] IntPtr parent );

// Defined on IFileDialog - repeated here due to requirements of COM interop layer
[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void SetFileTypes ( [In] uint cFileTypes, [In] COMDLG_FILTERSPEC[] rgFilterSpec );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void SetFileTypeIndex ( [In] uint iFileType );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void GetFileTypeIndex ( out uint piFileType );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void Advise ( [In, MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Interface )] IFileDialogEvents pfde, out uint pdwCookie );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void Unadvise ( [In] uint dwCookie );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void SetOptions ( [In] FOS fos );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void GetOptions ( out FOS pfos );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void SetDefaultFolder ( [In, MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Interface )] IShellItem psi );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void SetFolder ( [In, MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Interface )] IShellItem psi );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void GetFolder ( [MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Interface )] out IShellItem ppsi );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void GetCurrentSelection ( [MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Interface )] out IShellItem ppsi );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void SetFileName ( [In, MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] string pszName );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void GetFileName ( [MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] out string pszName );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void SetTitle ( [In, MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] string pszTitle );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void SetOkButtonLabel ( [In, MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] string pszText );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void SetFileNameLabel ( [In, MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] string pszLabel );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void GetResult ( [MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Interface )] out IShellItem ppsi );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void AddPlace ( [In, MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Interface )] IShellItem psi, NativeMethods.FDAP fdap );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void SetDefaultExtension ( [In, MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] string pszDefaultExtension );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void Close ( [MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Error )] int hr );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void SetClientGuid ( [In] ref Guid guid );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void ClearClientData ( );

// Not supported:  IShellItemFilter is not defined, converting to IntPtr
[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void SetFilter ( [MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Interface )] IntPtr pFilter );

// Defined by IFileOpenDialog
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void GetResults ( [MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Interface )] out IShellItemArray ppenum );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void GetSelectedItems ( [MarshalAs ( UnmanagedType.Interface )] out IShellItemArray ppsai );
}
```

If I'm only going to use two methods from this interface, can I define it like:

```
[ComImport, Guid ( "d57c7288-d4ad-4768-be02-9d969532d960" ), InterfaceType ( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
interface IFileOpenDialog : IFileDialog
{
// Defined on IModalWindow - repeated here due to requirements of COM interop layer
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime ), PreserveSig]
int Show ( [In] IntPtr parent );

[MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
void SetOptions ( [In] FOS fos );
}
```

Is it going to work? Or do I have to define the full interface with all methods?

Comment: Yes, if I only call the Show method, it works, if I try to call SetOptions, I get an exception: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this won't work.  The CLR builds a dispatch table for the COM interface based on the declaration.  The order of the function pointers in that table is set by the order of the method definitions in your declaration.  The Show() method will occupy the first slot in both cases, no trouble there.  SetOptions() however is going to end up calling the 2nd one, which is actually SetFileTypes().  They have different arguments, that's going to go kaboom in a nasty way when the implementation gets garbage arguments and the stack becomes unbalanced.

You *can* omit any declarations from the tail end.  Also note that the actual declaration of the method doesn't matter when you don't call it.  Which allows you to lie and avoid having to declare their argument types.  Do make sure it is obvious that the method won't actually work, name it something like *void DontCallMe2()*.

Note that these interfaces are already wrapped in the Windows API Code Pack as well as .NET 4.0's version of Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog and .NET 3.5's version of System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog

Comment: That's exactly what happens in my code: if I only call the Show method, it works, if I try to call SetOptions, I get an exception: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

So this is it? No way to cheat somehow? Do I have to define all methods up to SetOptions? Some of them may require additional WinAPI types definitions, so the code will quickly grow and grow...

Comment: Note that I edited my post to point out that this stuff is already done for you.

Comment: Yes, thank you, however I'm trying to work in .NET 2.0, as I think it has a larger installed user base (3.5 must be installed even on Vista, and 4.0 must be installed on Windows 7). And I think more XP machines have .NET 2.0 than 3.5 or 4.0. So if I work in .NET 2.0, the program runs directly on Windows 7, Windows Vista, and many XP machines that already have .NET 2.0

Comment: The .NET version is *not* tied to the Windows version, installing 4.0 on XP is not a problem.  Weighing the cost of you maintaining this code against a simple update is something only you can do.

Comment: Is there a way in which you can instruct the CLR to build the dispatch table for the COM interface and say that the SetOptions is actually on the 7th position, and not on the second?

Comment: Nope, there's no attribute for that.  You can just fill the slots with a dummy method, it doesn't have to be accurate when you don't call it.  Which allows you to avoid declaring their argument types, I guess that's what you are really after.  Do use a name for them that makes it obvious that it is a dummy, like "DontCallMe2()".

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you! I simply added Dummy in front of the method name: DummySetFileTypes. One more question: as you can see in MSDN or Pinvoke.net, IFileOpenDialog inherits from IFileDialog, and the Show and SetOptions methods I need are first defined in IFileDialog and then inherited in IFileOpenDialog. So I guess I have do to the dummy methods definitions on both interfaces, right? No way to make the code shorter?

Comment: Yes, COM interface inheritance requires support for multiple inheritance.  Not available in .NET, you have to repeat the method declarations for any of the base interfaces.  In the proper order, most deeply inherited interface first.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to define a type that implements an interface you're obliged to implement all elements of the interface. If you don't then the best case is that you'll get "erratic" behaviour from your code, the worst case is that your application will crash as soon as you try to do *anything* with your implementation of the interface.

Bear in mind that these two interfaces are *not* the same:

```
[ComImport, Guid ( "d57c7288-d4ad-4768-be02-9d969532d960" ), InterfaceType ( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
interface IFileOpenDialog : IFileDialog
{
    [MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime ), PreserveSig]
    int Show ( [In] IntPtr parent );
}

[ComImport, Guid ( "d57c7288-d4ad-4768-be02-9d969532d960" ), InterfaceType ( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
interface IFileOpenDialog : IFileDialog
{
    [MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime ), PreserveSig]
    int Show ( [In] IntPtr parent );

    [MethodImpl ( MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime )]
    void SetOptions ( [In] FOS fos );
}
```

Even though they have the same name, the same Guid and both implement `Show`, the fact that only one implements `SetOptions` makes them different.

**By all means, throw a `NotImplemented` exception from any methods of the interface you don't implement, but to say that you *implement interface `ISomeInterface`, you actually have to do so.**

Comment: This isn't actually true.  Calling the Show() method with either declaration works fine.  COM interfaces are identified by their Guid, not their declaration type.  This is what made the .NET 4.0 Type Equivalence feature possible, visible through the new 'Embed Interop Types' property of an assembly reference.